# In NHibernate (Fluent), How do you map a property on referenced object into parent object?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I want to map the `Name` column from the `Child` table into the `Parent` object. How do you do this (using Fluent NHibernate)?

```
public class Parent
{
   public int Key { get; set; }
   public string ChildName { get; set; }
}
```

Tables

```
+--------------+          +------------------+
| Parent       |          | Child            |
+--------------+          +------------------+
| Key      INT |     +--->| Key  INT         |
| ChildKey INT |-----+    | Name VARCHAR(20) |
+--------------+          +------------------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're trying to do just isn't a very good design, I'm afraid. Your `Parent` should have a relationship to the `Child` entity via a many-to-one (`References` in Fluent). That way you'd have a `Child` property in your `Parent` class.

If you're trying to produce a flattened model, I'd recommend you create a DTO and use something like Jimmy Bogard's [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) to flatten the hierarchy.

Comment: I was afraid this was going to be the case. The `Parent` class i'm trying to map to is a DTO and I was hoping the fluent mapping could handle the flattening, to avoid having to create a `Child` class.